# index out of range python

Tags: python, file, indexing, tuples

I'm trying to write a very simple program using tuples. Which works for the most part but I can't really get it to work by accessing individual elements in the tuples. 
I'm taking input from a file containing some info convert it to tuple and the store the data in some other file.

It works if I write all the data or just the first tuple but not in any other case. Following is the code

```
filename = "in.txt"
stock_market = []
for line in open(filename):
    fields = line.split(",")
    name = fields[0]
    shares = int(fields[1])
    stock = (name,shares)
    portfolio.append(stock)
    f = open("output.txt","w")
    print >>f, portfolio[1]
    f.close()
```

Comment: Show the actual traceback, or at least tell us which line the error is on. We can't reproduce it ourselves without a sample of your data file.

Comment: Is this your actual code? `stock_market` is never used, and `portfolio` is never initialized. Also, `print >>f, portfolio[1]` is equivalent to "write the contents of the second element of `portfolio` to the file". What happens when `portfolio` has fewer than two elements? Remember, the list `[(a,b)]` has a length of one.

Comment: Why are you opening and closing `output.txt` for every line of the input? (Also, are you intentionally truncating the output every time, or did you mean to open the file with mode `"a"`?)

Answer (score 0):

You can't append to portfolio without defining it first. Try something like this:

> ```
> inFilename = "in.txt"
> outFilename = "output.txt"
> with open(inFilename, 'r') as inf:
>     with open(outFilename, 'w') as outf:
>         for line in inf:
>             fields = line.split(',')
>             print >>outf, (fields[0], fields[1])
> ```